# Angular2 with Auth0, do I need to hide my ClientID and domain?

Tags: angular, auth0

I've been using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to build the front-end user authentication part of my site, but am unsure if I should be following the documentation exactly.

If I want to build a commercial product, **should I be hiding the client ID and domain? Is this something that would lead to a security breach?**

Currently anyone can view my Angular2 source code and look at the client ID and domain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **client identifier and your domain** (which I'm assuming you're referring to the assigned Auth0 domain similar to `[account].auth0.com`) **are both considered information that does not need to be kept secret**.

The domain represents the entity handling the authentication; the equivalent of `accounts.google.com` for your application.

The client identifier is defined within the OAuth 2.0 specification which clearly indicates that is not confidential information:

> The client identifier is not a secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used alone for client authentication.

In browser-based or other application where the actual code is located in a client environment it's unavoidable to have information stored there for authentication purposes. You just need to be sure that the information stored is okay to be disclosed like it is with the two examples you gave.

On the other hand these types of application could not securely use a client secret as it is defined by OAuth 2.0, because like you said, anyone could see it by inspecting the code.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, I do I see a potential danger of this. Let's say I am a hacker, I could build up a site that looks like the target site, using the clientID and domain that I "take" from the target. The users think they are logging in to the site. After authenticated, I could use the return token to do all kinds of bad things as it is my client code that is running. I think due to this danger, you do not want just anyone being able to use your clientID and domain?

Comment: According to OAuth2 rules you would need to specify a redirect URL where to receive the token; the set of redirect URLs available to use in association with the client ID you were trying to impersonate are pre-registered and validated when performing an OAuth request. Your fake client could start the request, but if it specified a valid redirect URL that is not under his control then it would never receive the token, if it tried to specify a redirect URL under the fake client control, the request would fail validation.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.