# Where to store Auth0 domain and client id?

Tags: reactjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, auth0

I'm trying to understand how to securely store Auth0 DOMAIN and CLIENT ID. 
Looking at this example app https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/Auth/auth0-variables.js.example, seems like they had it stored somewhere else.

Would appreciate if someone can give me some insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you have given wants you put your credentials there. You can tell that by the quotes:

```
domain: '{DOMAIN}',
clientId: '{CLIENT_ID}',
```

So, you will put your credentials like:

```
domain: 'some domain here',
clientId: 'some client id here',
```

Then those credentials are being imported by Auth.js file. They don't import them anywhere as you you thought, they just don't need to hide them since domain and client id does not need to be kept as secret.

You can find a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40378764/7060441) explaining why they are not `secrets` for frontend.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I didnt realize that domain and client id doesn't need to be secured and ok to be hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentioned, you dont need to secure those specific variables. But if you are curious, On production securing sensitive data is done through environment variables.

You can create a .env file in the root of your project and then import the variables as

process.env.NAME_OF_PROPERTY

Here is a helper library for node and React apps: 
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Comment: A simple misconfiguration (such as running a production server in debug mode) or a security bug could result in the leak of all the environment variables. If you want to really secure secrets you use a secret management tool like Vault.